# Why do I have extra padding in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, padding

I have written a code with a row inside which is another column. But for some reason there is this extra padding which I don't want. How can I remove it? Also, what is the cause of it.
[image]

This is my code:

```
import 'package:brew_crew_firebase_tut/models/brew.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BrewTile extends StatefulWidget {
  Brew brew;
  BrewTile({ super.key, required this.brew });

  @override
  State<BrewTile> createState() => _BrewTileState();
}

class _BrewTileState extends State<BrewTile> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Brew brew = widget.brew;
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 20),
      child: Card(child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            CircleAvatar(backgroundColor:Colors.brown[brew.strength], backgroundImage: AssetImage("assets/coffee_icon.png"),),
            SizedBox(width: 10,),
            Column(
              children: [
                Text(brew.name, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                Text("Takes ${brew.sugars} sugars", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[600]),),
              ],
              )
          ],
        ),
      ),),
    );
  }
}
```

It was just fine but I don't know for some reason it abruptly came there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add:

```
 crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start
```

To your Column, like this:

```
 Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
       Text(brew.name, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 
       FontWeight.bold),),
       Text("Takes ${brew.sugars} sugars", style: TextStyle(color: 
       Colors.grey[600]),),
    ],
 )
```